# Passing params back and forth between excel vba and c#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I'm trying to use C# with excel and vba. I wrote with VS Express a library dll and everything went well as long I used only unique cells in Excel as one or many parameters. Then I tried something else using a cell range of 2 x 2 in the few lines below.

```
public class TryRange
{
    public double Sum1(object [,] r1)
    {
        int col1 = r1.GetLength(0);
        int row1 = r1.GetLength(1);
        double tmp = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < row1; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < col1; c++)
            {
                tmp = tmp + (double)(r1[r, c]);
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

and to test in Excel these lines in vba

```
Public Function Try1(x As Variant) As Double
' name space in C# is ExcelVbaOne
Dim obj As ExcelVbaOne.TryRange
Dim y As Double

Set obj = New ExcelVbaOne.TryRange
Set y = obj.Sum1(x)
Essai1 = y
End Function
```

In C# I tried to use Excel.Range r1 with MicrosoftOffice.Interop.Excel instead of object [,] r1. I tried y = obj.Sum1(x) ... But either the vba program breaks at the line invocating the C# Sum1(x) or the Excel cell displays "VALUE!".
Can someone help?

Comment: ...`Try1` vs `Essai1` is just a flaw and not in your code?

Comment: @KekuSemau It's a flaw and not in the code (passing from French to English in order to be more understandable ... but I forgot to change the last "Essai1" word, sorry for that!